# Regex syntax error with Sed command in Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: regex, linux, bash, ubuntu, sed

I have the sed command like this:

```
radius_clientsfile=clients.conf
iface_netsize="/64"
wireless_prefix=fd04:bd3:80e8:3::
sed -i "/client $wireless_prefix\\$iface_netsize/ {n s/\(\W*secret\W*=\W\).*/\1$key/}" $radius_clientsfile
```

clients.conf has the content like this:

```
client fd04:bd3:80e8:3::/64 {
  secret      = 00000000000000000000000000000001
}
```

which aim to replace value of secret by key in clients.conf file. For Example, if key is 00000000000000000000000000000002, the content of clients.conf should be changed as following:

```
client fd04:bd3:80e8:3::/64 {
      secret      = 00000000000000000000000000000002
    }
```

This script work on OpenWRT attitude adjustment r35400 for armv5tejl
However, it can not work in Ubuntu 9.04 with error:
 *sed: -e expression #1, char 36: extra characters after command*

Could anyone help me for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need add a `;` between command `n` and command `s`, like this

```
sed -i "/client $wireless_prefix\\$iface_netsize/ {n; s/\(\W*secret\W*=\W\).*/\1$key/}" $radius_clientsfile
```

This working in my cygwin environment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the commands in the command block with a semi-colon, so add a ; after the n command to separate it from the following command.

Like this:

```
{n;s/\(\W*secret\W*=\W\).*/\1$key/}
```